# Error compiling altcoin-qt for Windows, getting a GCC internal compiler error

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, development, protocol, altcoin

I think I managed to get all my dependencies and libraries right (fingers crossed), but now when trying to build blackcoin-qt, the QTSdk compiler gives me this error while building qtipcserver.o:

```
In function 'bool boost::interprocess::winapi::unlink_file(const char*)':
internal compiler error: in gimple_rhs_has_side_effects, at gimple.c:2343
[build/qtipcserver.o] Error1
```

The unlink_file function is on line 1638 of win32_api.hpp in the boost library. This seems like a GCC error, any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=304389.0

Answer (score 1):

Most likely cause: the compiler ran out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know it helps you or not but there is a very good instructions for developing your coin on windows here:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0

Comment: IIRC the issue is that BTCTalk's post (link you posted) is incomplete. I don't know what is missing but if you really need to bring ANOTHER altcoin to market just do it through CoinSource who do so for a fee

Answer (score 0):

"Internal compiler error" indicates a bug in gcc (or possibly a fault in your hardware, especially if it's not reproducible). Check that you have the latest gcc version. Otherwise, report it to the gcc maintainers, and/or start debugging gcc yourself. There isn't really anything cryptocoin-specific here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Eldredge. It's a compiler bug or less likely a hardware problem.

The usual fix is to make sure you are using the latest gcc and boost. Be wary of the current gcc 4.9. Its reported to have bugs.